# check if value in pandas column has same start of another column

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, text, conditional-statements

As the title says I'm trying to think about a condition to use in my code. I have the following dataset:

```
 key1   key2    ColumnToSum
  345    347        2
  234    453        5 
  263    234        2 
  321    321        5
  345    347        8
  234    453        8 
  263    234        8 
  321    321        8
```

I want 4 conditions:

1. See key1 and key2 are equal
2. See if the first two digits of key1 are equal to the first two digits of key2
3. See if the first digit of key1 is equal to the first digit of key2
4. See if key1 is completely different from key2

Current solutions in the same order:

```
 dataset["key1"].eq(dataset["key2"])  #WORKING

 dataset["key1"][0:2].eq(dataset["key2"][0:2]) #NOT WORKING

 dataset["key1"][0].eq(dataset["key2"][0]) #NOT WORKING

 #No ideas
```

I really appreciate your time and effort
Looking forward to hear your opinion

Comment: What do you mean by "completely different" in 4th condition? If all digits are different or records are not equal?

Answer (score 0):

If you have strings, you can use the [`str`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.Series.str.html) accessor:

```
dataset['key1'] = dataset['key1'].astype(str).zfill(3) # ensure 3 digits
dataset['key2'] = dataset['key2'].astype(str).zfill(3) # to prevent 30x and 30
dataset["key1"].str[0:2].eq(dataset["key2"].str[0:2])  # to match
```

for integers, use floor division [`floordiv`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.Series.floordiv.html):

```
# remove 1 digit by dividing by 10, 2 by 100, etc.
dataset["key1"].floordiv(10).eq(dataset["key2"].floordiv(10))
```

example output:

```
0     True
1    False
2    False
3     True
4     True
5    False
6    False
7     True
dtype: bool
```